# Cisco 3560 snmpget OID temperature not found?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, snmp

I'm working on creating a monitor script for some access layer switches. I've gotten it to work with some Cisco 3750s, but when I try it on a Cisco 3560, it says the OID object not found. After looking at Cisco's MIB locator, it is the same for both platforms. Am I missing something here?

```
montorbox# snmpget -v1 -c public 10.x.x.x 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3.1.3
Error in packet
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
```

I've added my monitor server to the SNMP server host group. Do I have to load something additional onto the switch?

Comment: It looks like you may be missing the [instance subidentifier](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/FAQ.html#Why_do_I_get__noSuchName__when_asking_for__sysUpTime___or_similar__). You can find what your missing by performing an [snmpwalk](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/man/snmpwalk.html) on that OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3.1.3`. If there are multiple 3560s in a stack then you'll have more than one instance subidentifier for the `ciscoEnvMonTemperatureStatusValue` object.

Comment: Thanks, still getting no such object at this OID. They are not stacked in this case.

Comment: Have you tried changing your SNMP version to 2? `snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.x.x.x 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3.1.3` to get your instance subidentifier and then `snmpget -v2c -c public 10.x.x.x 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3.1.3.isid`.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

`1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3.1.3` is an OID for `ciscoEnvMonTemperatureStatusTable`in `CISCO-ENVMON-MIB`, and it is marked as `MAX-ACCESS not-accessible` in mib. So, snmpget will always fail on it:

`snmpget -v1 -c public abn21 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3
Error in packet
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.13.1.3`

But snmpwalk will succeed:

`snmpwalk -v1 -c public abn21 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.13.1.3.1.2.1005 = STRING: "SW#1, Sensor#1, GREEN "
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.13.1.3.1.3.1005 = Gauge32: 29
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.13.1.3.1.4.1005 = INTEGER: 59
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.13.1.3.1.5.1005 = INTEGER: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.13.1.3.1.6.1005 = INTEGER: 1`

The same with cisco mibs in /usr/share/snmp/CISCO:

`snmpwalk -v1 -c public -M /usr/share/snmp/CISCO  -m CISCO-ENVMON-MIB -IR abn21 ciscoEnvMonTemperatureStatusTable
CISCO-ENVMON-MIB::ciscoEnvMonTemperatureStatusDescr.1005 = STRING: SW#1, Sensor#1, GREEN 
CISCO-ENVMON-MIB::ciscoEnvMonTemperatureStatusValue.1005 = Gauge32: 29 degrees Celsius
CISCO-ENVMON-MIB::ciscoEnvMonTemperatureThreshold.1005 = INTEGER: 59 degrees Celsius
CISCO-ENVMON-MIB::ciscoEnvMonTemperatureLastShutdown.1005 = INTEGER: 0 degrees Celsius
CISCO-ENVMON-MIB::ciscoEnvMonTemperatureState.1005 = INTEGER: normal(1)`

Note snmp entries ids like `1.2`, `1.3` ... and sensor instance `1005` (may vary in your case)  in snmpwalk output - using such complete OID you can access table entries directly with snmpget:

`snmpget -v1 -c public  abn21 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3.1.2.1005
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.13.1.3.1.2.1005 = STRING: "SW#1, Sensor#1, GREEN "`

PS: snmp version (1 or 2c) doesn't matter here.